# Problems with conversion from theme.res to thema.css

Tags: css, codenameone

I have an app for the 2018 World Cup calendar and I want to update it to 2022. I ran into a couple of problems:

1. The form in the title used to show a background image and now I can't get it to appear. I have tried with tbMenu.getTitleComponent().setUIID("TitleArea"); and it does not work.

   TitleArea {
   background-image: url(images/rojo.png);
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "native:MainBold";
   font-size: 3.5mm;
   }
2. I also put buttons that change when pressing a forward or back command and now it only shows the first time and when I press the command the area appears blank.
   Try "tbMenu.setTitleComponent(cnP);" which works for the first time but it doesn't update when i press the command.

I appreciate the support

---

Hi,

I have placed an image in drive because stackoverflow sends me an error when trying to place it. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LVBZPMCTTTEZxEYfwrh3S2_fPzyktTiN

As you can see, I tried several combinations and not from what I deduced the problem is about the title area because in certain parts it works. I copy the changes I made to the CSS and the image shows the result in the hope that it will tell me which is the correct way.

```
Title {
    background-image: url(images/titulo.png);
    cn1-background-type: cn1-image-scaled-fill;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "native:MainBold";
    font-size: 3.5mm;
}

TitleArea {
    background-image: url(images/titulo.png);
    cn1-background-type: cn1-image-scaled-fill;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "native:MainBold";
    font-size: 10mm;
}

TitleCommand {
    background-image: url(images/titulo.png);
    cn1-background-type: cn1-image-scaled-fill;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "native:MainBold";
    font-size: 10mm;
}
TitleCustom {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "native:MainBold";
    font-size: 3.5mm;
}
```

I also include the method where I load the titles for the first time.

```
        final Toolbar tbMenu = new Toolbar();
        this.setToolBar(tbMenu);

        Vector vGP = grupoResultadosActivos("A");
        Container cnP = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Label lbTitulo = new Label("GRUPO A");
        lbTitulo.setUIID("Title");
        cnP.addComponent(lbTitulo);
        if (vGP.size() > 0) {
            int cnt = contadorBarraPaises(vGP);
            if (cnt > 0) {
                cnP.addComponent(cargaBarraPaises(vGP, cnt));
            }
        }
        cnTitleArea.add(cnP);
        cnTitleArea.setUIID("TitleCustom");
        tbMenu.setTitleComponent(cnTitleArea);
        tbMenu.repaint();
```

Comment: I see several problems in the code. First I would suggest using the default toolbar where possible. Second, you never need `repaint()` when building stuff and it can cause harm (albeit unlikely). Third, what's `cnTitleArea`? Where do you set it? Do you just add stuff to the title area? That's very problematic. You should only use the title component and not add stuff to the title area.
What I wanted to see was a screenshot of the component inspector tool you can see in the simulator. You can actually see the hierarchy and traverse it to understand what's going on.

Comment: This was recently revised in the current version. See Figure 1 here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-property-sheet-and-javadocs.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with things like this. I suggest using the component inspector and reviewing the components in the hierarchy to see what went through then editing the CSS dynamically to see the changes.

**Important:** sometimes changes don't apply in this way!

You will need to stop the simulator and delete the res file. Then do a clean build. It's rare but it happens in some configurations and might be misleading.

About the specific issues. For the first try adding:

```css
cn1-background-type: cn1-image-scaled-fill;
```

`setTitleComponent` is problematic since it overrides the entire title area. Many generic behaviors will stop working if you do that. It's an all or nothing situation and might be the reason other things don't work.

Comment: I was able to solve the button problem (point 2) by including a container and using the replace method to change the countries.
 but it has been impossible for me to change the background image of the toolbar (point 1). I found that I have the same problem in dialog boxes as I also use an image in the toolbar. Do you have any other ideas to solve this?

Comment: I'll need more information. Try finding the component in the component inspector. Does it have other components on top that hide it? What's the UIID? If you set other properties there do they have an impact? Assuming you're still stuck just edit the question with screenshots.